# Why do books write $X(f)$ when they mean actually mean $\lvert X(f)\rvert$?

Tags: fourier-transform

All books write $X(f)$ in plots - the Fourier transform of $x(t)$ - when they actually mean $\lvert X(f)\rvert$, without even mentioning in passing that they are dropping the mod sign.  And also they consider only the mod of FT in the analysis, completely ignoring the phase term - especially communications analysis like AM and FM. Why?  It is well known that in image processing phase also place an important role?  Is there any proof or valid reason that phase is unimportant in communication engineering?

Comment: Are the books you talk about Fourier transforming real or complex functions?

Comment: We talk about the general functions - complex functions.  In communications, we deal with signals that are originally real.  But for ease of use and analysis and manipulation, we consider their complex versions.  Analytic etc.   But even the real functions do have imaginary part of FT.  That is, even the real functions do have phase terms.

Comment: Ok, for the general case, I have no idea why they would do this. But the Fourier transform of even real functions is purely real, and the Fourier transform of odd real functions is purely imaginary, so in these cases there would be no phase.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Please provide precise reference to claim.

Comment: But not all communication signals are even.  And odd signals do have the phase if they have only imaginary part in their FTs.

Comment: I just checked a couple of books on my shelf.  None of them exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Majority of the books, if not all, I used so far do as I mentioned.  One reason could be that otherwise they would have to show real and imaginary (or amplitude and phase) spectra separately.  But they can mention at least mod in stead of simply showing X(f). I can give examples but I do not know if I should single out some.

Comment: Another facet is that they consider amplitude spectrum only when talking about the recovery of the signal - through different types of  filtering etc.  Why do they ignore what happens to the phase through these operations?

Comment: @SeethaRamaRajuSanapala: The question we'd like to know is *what books are making this claim.* Please provide Author & Title information.

Comment: OK.  For example - Radar Principles by Peyton Z Peebles.  page 252.  Plot S(w) vs. w.  Strictly, if S(w) is complex, you can not plot S(w) vs. w.  Unless you draw 3-d plot. Or  you have to plot mod of S(w) or phase of S(w) separately against w.  This is only an example.  Uniformly followed by other books too.